# jQuery selectors. Why only first child is reacting?

Tags: jquery

Okay I'm doing this bit of jQuery and can't seem get to work all children.
Only first child does what it says .. it is appending an error line.
Why the others being ignored ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var firstName = $('input[name=firstName]').val();
    var lastName = $('input[name=lastName]').val();
    var email = $('input[name=email]').val();
    var address = $('input[name=addressBox').val();
    var phoneNum = $('input[name=phoneNumber').val();
    var dob = $('input[name=dob').val();

$('#submitbtn').click(function() {

    if (firstName.length < 2) {
        $("form label:first-child").append("<p class='turnsRed'>You need to enter your first name</p>");
    } else if (lastName.length < 2) {           
        $("form label:nth-child(3)").append("<p class='turnsRed'>You need to enter your last name</p>");
    } else if (address.length < 2) {
        $("form label:nth-child(4)").append("<p class='turnsRed'>You need to enter your address</p>");
    } else if (dob.length < 1) {
        $("form label:nth-child(5)").append("<p class='turnsRed'>You need to enter your date of birth</p>");
    } else if (email.length < 2) {
        $("form label:nth-child(6)").append("<p class='turnsRed'>You need to enter your email</p>");
    } else if (phoneNum.length < 1) { 
        $("form label:nth-child(7)").append("<p class='turnsRed'>You need to enter your phone number</p>");

    };

});
});
```

html bit looks like this:

```
<form>
    <label for="first name">Your first name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value=""><br>
    <label for="middle name">Your middle name (optional)</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="middle name" value=""><br>
    <label for="last name">Your last name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value=""><br>
    <label for="your address">Your address (inc. zip/post code)</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="addressBox" value=""><br>
    <input type="text" name="addressBox" value=""><br>
    <input type="text" name="addressBox" value=""><br>
    <input type="text" name="addressBox" value=""><br>
    <label for="dof">Your date of birth</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="dob" value=""><br>
    <label for="your email">Your email</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" value=""><br>
    <label for="phone number">Your mobile phone number</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="phoneNumber" value="">

</form>
```

Second child is deliberately left out 'coz it's linked to middle name which is optional.

Comment: Did you mean to write `if` instead of `else if`?

Comment: Need to show html structure also. See [mcve]

Comment: else if doesn't work in jQuery ???

Comment: Of course `else if` works in jQuery (it is, after all, still JavaScript), but it seems. Looking at your code, that you want to show multiple errors I'd there are multiple errors; whereas an `if` / `else if` will stop at the first matching condition.

Comment: Ohh .... I completely forgotten that if/else works this way. It won't react to all criterias met only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

`var firstName = $('input[name=firstName]').val();`

this returns the value of the input **at this moment.**

After a while, when you click the button, `firstName` still remain the before value.

So, you need to do is getting the value dynamically.

Comment: Also I deliberately left second child intact 'coz entering middle name is optional but what's odd is error line that belongs to Date of Birth label is being appended to second child ! The only child that has no class and not being modified.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you are getting input values at once on the document ready event so your code is not aware of changes. Move your getters in click event and you will be able to get theirs latest value. I have made some improvements considering this on your code as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitbtn').click(function() {      
        var firstName = $('input[name=firstName]').val();
        var lastName = $('input[name=lastName]').val();
        var email = $('input[name=email]').val();
        var address = $('input[name=addressBox]').val(); // typo
        var phoneNum = $('input[name=phoneNumber]').val(); // typo
        var dob = $('input[name=dob]').val(); // typo

        // Remove old warnings in case of duplication
        $("form .turnsRed").remove();

        if (firstName.length < 2) {
            $("form label:first-child").append("<p class='turnsRed'>You need to enter your first name</p>");
        } else if (lastName.length < 2) {           
            $("form label:nth-child(3)").append("<p class='turnsRed'>You need to enter your last name</p>");
        } else if (address.length < 2) {
            $("form label:nth-child(4)").append("<p class='turnsRed'>You need to enter your address</p>");
        } else if (dob.length < 1) {
            $("form label:nth-child(5)").append("<p class='turnsRed'>You need to enter your date of birth</p>");
        } else if (email.length < 2) {
            $("form label:nth-child(6)").append("<p class='turnsRed'>You need to enter your email</p>");
        } else if (phoneNum.length < 1) { 
            $("form label:nth-child(7)").append("<p class='turnsRed'>You need to enter your phone number</p>");
        };
    });
});
```

On your validation part, if you want to validate all the values at the same time you must remove else if conditions.

Comment: Hmm ..... so I need to work only with IFs ? Okay as long as it's gonna work. What do you mean by // typo ???

Comment: If you want to show all the validation errors at the same time, yes. If you want to show them one by one then your code is alright. I have added typo comments because you did not close attribute tags of the marked inputs correctly.

Comment: Appreciate you feedback but can't find any typos in it.

Comment: By typo I meant to say you have not correctly closed your attribute tags. However, your problem was not that at all, it was just a quick tip. Is the answer helped you out?